# How call several commands by one commands?

Tags: macros

If you want to write an algorithm, you have to write three commands to initialize a writing environment.

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{algorithm} % no.1
\begin{algorithmic} % no.2
\Procedure{Sum}{100} % no.3
\State abcd
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

And write three lines to end it. So is there any way to wrap it up, using one command to simplify it?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `myalgorithm` environment (you can call it anything you want) that does this. If you add

```
\newenvironment{myalgorithm}[2]
  {\begin{algorithm}\begin{algorithmic}\Procedure{#1}{#2}}
  {\EndProcedure\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}}
```

you can use this in your document as

```
\begin{myalgorithm}{Sum}{100}
  \State abcd
\end{myalgorithm}
```

The two arguments are those that are given to the `\Procedure` command. Note that this will not allow you to add a caption or label to the `algorithm` floating environment.